# Multiple range sliders with jQuery (updating inputs)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this nice example of a range slider with updating input fields:

http://jsfiddle.net/FPCRb/1/

I did manage to create multiple ranged sliders from that

```
$( ".slider" ).each(function() {
   $( this ).slider({
   ...
```

but updating the inputs via:

```
$("input.sliderValue[data-index=" + i + "]").val(ui.values[i]);
```

and updating the slider via:

```
$("input.sliderValue").change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $("#slider").slider("values", $this.data("index"), $this.val());
});
```

of course doesn't work. How could this be extended in a nice way?

Comment: Seems to work fine here? Chrome 36 on OSX

Comment: Works fine for me too: updating the inputs from the slider and vice-versa.

Comment: Working also... Maybe you want to improve the input update for special value? (For example minSlider > maxSlider case, ..;)

Comment: Yeah i want multiple Ranged sliders with two inputs for each one :)

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/FPCRb/1631/

Comment: Very nice Anton! Thanks!